# how to upgrade magento enterprise edition

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade

How to upgrade magento enterprise edition. Unlike community edition enterprise edition does not have facility to upgrade from one version to another version using from Magento Connect. In Magento community edition we can upgrade from one version to newer version using magento connect and check for updates. If any updates found we simply check those modules and go for update. 
In Enterprise edition if I choose check for updates in magento connect, nothing is coming out even though newer version is available.
So please let me know how to upgrade magento enterprise edition from older version to newer version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy the files from the new version over your old Magento instance, clear the cache, hit refresh button on the browser ...wait...hope for the best. This usually worked for me. And backup before trying it (code and db).

Comment: @Marius thanks for reply. but will it works. According  to magentocommerce.com they have provided different scenario http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-upgrading    Which I have not understood

Comment: They may be right. I haven't done an upgrade to 1.13 before. I didn't realize it can be different. My "ugliest" upgrade was from CE 1.1 to EE 1.9 and it worked as I described (almost smoothly). I thought it will work the same. It doesn't hurt to give it a try (not on live), maybe you are lucky.

Comment: What version are you upgrading from? This is very important~!!

Answer (score 3):

Copy the files in-place over top of your local development server's copy. Hopefully you're using version control software so you can commit your changes for deployment at a later date after your testing phase.

**On Linux:**

```
cp -R ./Magento_Enterprise_1.13.1.0/ /var/www/vhosts/yourmagentoinstalllocation/webroot
```

**On Mac OSX**

This is a little trickier because the target will be replaced entirely, no merging will happen. Because of this, instead of using CP, use Ditto:

```
ditto ./Magento_Enterprise_1.13.1.0/ /var/www/vhosts/yourmagentoinstalllocation/webroot
```

On PC just copy and paste over top, choosing to replace duplicate filenames.

**Upgrading to EE 1.13+**

You will need to prepare your URLs prior to upgrade, and there are various tools provided to do this. You can download those toolkits from the Magento Partner portal and run against your database in-place. Obviously before you do any of the above you should backup and test your backup to ensure the safety of your installation.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-later-release-notes#ee113-11302-patches